# Compute Tensor Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Compute the dimension of the tensor products of two algebras $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Is $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ finite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ ?(Problem 4 in UCLA 2020 june phd algebra exam)

For the first one, I use basis such as $1 \otimes \sqrt{2}$ over Q to prove its dim is 4(Or by distribution law). For the second one, I think its dim 2  because $\sqrt{2} \otimes 1 \ and\ 1\otimes 1$ but for technique in the link answer below.I think $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ might be isomorphic. I don't know which is true.

For the last one, I think I could define a surjective homorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  by $1 \otimes r \to r$ ,where r belong to the basis of R over $\mathbb{Q}$. then we get $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a surjective homorphism. then by card relation between $\mathbb{Q} \  and \ \mathbb{R} $ we get its infinite demension on R.But by [As a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, is $\mathbb{R}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167737/as-a-mathbbz-module-is-mathbbr-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbr-isomorphi?rq=1) I think I am wrong but have no idea for which part. And in the link answer, why I could not do one side direct product to form $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_Z R =R$ and then by distribution law to form infinite dimension space over R?

For which part I get wrong?Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4127142/tensor-product-of-quadratic-number-field-with-itself?rq=1 there is a detailed procedure in the linked answer for the first question